# parse date from filepath with python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file path like the example below.  I would like to parse the date portion out of it, like the example output below.  Does anyone have a suggestion how to do this?

input:

```
path='/home/user/backup_2021-05-01.091501.sql'
```

output:

```
'2021-05-01'
```

Comment: well if it always has `backup_` prefix you can split it like `date=path.split("_")[1]`, then you have `2021-05-01.091501.sql`, now you can split this result for `.` with `date= date.split(".")[0]` and you have required date. So to do it at once you could do `date=path.split("_")[1].split(".")[0]` I am sure there is some fancy one liner to do it more pythonic way.

Comment: or you could ofc use `regex` library as re with something like `re.search("([0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2})", path)`

Comment: @BijayRegmi You might want to point out that the result of re.search is not a string but a match object that has to be converted by using ``group()``